# Replacement of dict type for numba as parameters of a python function

Tags: python, numba

In my code, there are a lot of parameters which are constant during the running. I defined a `dict` type variable to store them. But I find that `numba` cannot support `dict`.

What is a better way to solve this?

Comment: Could you add a bit more context so that it's actually obvious what you mean, what doesn't work and how it should work :)

Comment: OK, I will add. I use dictionary  to reduce the number of parameters in a function. And I hope to speed up the function with `numba`, but `numba` does not support dict type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a function like this and you are fine by accessing it as attribute instead of by subscript:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def func(config):
    return config.c
```

You could use a `collections.namedtuple` here (like @JoshAdel mentioned):

```
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple

conf = namedtuple('conf', ['a', 'b', 'c'])

func(conf(1, 2.0, np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int64)))
# array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Or a jitclass:

```
spec = [('a', nb.int64),
        ('b', nb.float64),
        ('c', nb.int64[:])]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class Conf:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

func(Conf(1, 2.0, np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int64)))
# array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

These can't replace all functionalities of a dictionary but these allow to pass in "a lot of parameters" as one instance.

Comment: Thanks very much! `JoshAdel` and `MSeifert`. I think this is exactly what I need. Thanks for the examples.

Comment: @W.Zhao No problem - I'm glad *if* it works (it was a bit of a long shot). Please also don't forget to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all helpful answers and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the one that helped you most.

Answer (score 3):

Numba supports `namedtuples` in `nopython` mode, which should be a good alternative to a `dict` for passing a large group of parameters into a numba jitted function.